# How to encrypt javascript and php in source code?

Tags: javascript

I am trying hide or encrypt my javascript code from source code.

my code is :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function getValue() {

    return "<?php echo "ab"; ?>";

}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form name="form">
        An input field:
        <input type="text" name="input">
        <input type="submit" name="submit">
    </form>
<script type="text/javascript">

        document.form.input.value = getValue();

    </script>
```

Please help.

Comment: What you're trying to achieve is unclear (or awful but let's be optimistic).

Answer (score 0):

You can't encrypt JavaScript code from source code, but you can optimize it by using JavaScript minimizers like this:

http://www.minifyjavascript.com/

Comment: Encrypting javascript isn't hard. Apart if you want the browser to be able to run it, of course.

Comment: I am trying to encrypt it not to compress it.